# How to change navigation bar properties only on one viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, hide

I'm struggling with doing something with navigation bar on first viewcontroller and only on it. I used `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`. I tried this in several ways, including using negation to this code on the rest of viewcontrollers. But they behave always the same.

Comment: i am using button to show you how the code works. if you dont want to use button setup a `barButtonItem`  to your `navigationBar`?.if i understand currently you want to hide navBar upon swipe in 1st VC not other VC follows the swipe behaviour?

Comment: let me know.which controller you want to hide navBar..update your post with storyBoard screenshot and point out what you want.so, i can get a better look...

Comment: I wondering you using my answer in vc1 or vc2?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in `Swift 3`

**Note:** Below code only hides `navigationBar` on first VC.When swipes.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This code behaves like: when I swipe to hide and click button, on "vc2" there is no bar and it's kinda tricky to use it